# Wodpress передать данные с php в javascript

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Добрый день, пишу виджет для Wordpress для себя и хотел бы узнать как передавать данные с одного файла php в файл js. Написал вот такое:

```
php file widget_init.php:

<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'gw-instagramm', plugins_url('js/gw-instagramm.js', __FILE__) );

$dataToBePassed = array(
    'username'            => 'user',
    'photonum' => 9
);
wp_localize_script( 'gw-instagramm', 'php_vars', $datatoBePassed );


?>
```

js файл:

```
var gwInstagramm;
(function($) {

gwInstagramm = {
    someFunction: function() {
        // тут должно выводиться username & photonum
    }
}
}(jQuery));
```

Не работает. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: а что именно не работает? скрипт вызывается? someFunction хоть что-то выводит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал, кому интересно как вот JS код:

```
var gwInstagramm;
(function($) {

gwInstagramm = {
    someFunction: function() {
        php_vars.username,
        php_vars.photonum
    }
}
}(jQuery));
```